# SQL Read Table Between dates, if nothing exists still write as empty

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, between

I am reading from three different tables which works fine.

```
SELECT id AS Projekt_ID, cu.name AS Projektname, effort AS Ist FROM cost_unit cu 
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT p.cost_unit_id, SUM(te.effort) AS effort, p.id AS id
                    FROM time_entry te, project p, activity a
                    WHERE te.task = a.uuid AND a.costunit = p.cost_unit_id AND te.date BETWEEN
                    'firstTime'
                    AND
                    'secondTime'
                    GROUP BY p.cost_unit_id, p.id)te ON cu.uuid = te.cost_unit_id
                    WHERE id = " + ar[0]
```

as you can see, I handle the dates and a project ID with variables, but as mentioned before, everything works fine.

The problem is, I only get data from the table which is exactly between that dates. 
But I need everything, and if there are no time entries in that table between that dates I need them to be empty, or better said as 0,00.

What could I change to make this work? It is PostreSQL, FYI

Comment: Which is the version of SQL Server  - there are useful functions in newer versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ID field is not from cost_unit, but from subquery with LEFT join.
Try to get project in main part of query

```
SELECT p.id AS Projekt_ID, cu.name AS Projektname, coalesce(effort, 0)  AS Ist 
FROM cost_unit cu 
INNER JOIN project p on p.cost_unit_id = cu.uuid
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT a.costunit, SUM(te.effort) AS effort
    FROM time_entry te,  activity a
    WHERE te.task = a.uuid 
    AND te.date BETWEEN
                    'firstTime'
                    AND
                    'secondTime'
    GROUP BY a.costunit)te ON te.costunit = p.cost_unit_id
WHERE id = " + ar[0]
```

Comment: Works, thanks for the help, now I have only to change it in my code and my work is done :)

Answer (score 0):

If i am understanding your question correctly i use a table of dates to do this.

If i have a table with all relevant dates in it maybe like this:

```
Date
01/01/2015
02/01/2015
...
31/12/2017
```

then you could modify your query something like this (may have issues but i hope you get the idea):

```
Select 
    d.Date
    ,Projekt_ID
    ,Projektname
    ,Ist
FROM
    DatesTable as d
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
            SELECT 
                id AS Projekt_ID
                , cu.name AS Projektname
                , effort AS Ist 
                ,te.date
            FROM 
                cost_unit cu 
                LEFT OUTER JOIN (
                            SELECT 
                                p.cost_unit_id
                                , SUM(te.effort) AS effort
                                , p.id AS id
                                ,te.date
                            FROM 
                                time_entry te
                                , project p
                                , activity a
                            WHERE 
                                te.task = a.uuid 
                                AND a.costunit = p.cost_unit_id 
                            GROUP BY 
                                p.cost_unit_id
                                , p.id
                                )te 
                    ON cu.uuid = te.cost_unit_id
            WHERE id = " + ar[0]"
            ) i
        on d.Date = i.Date
    WHERE
        d.date BETWEEN
        'firstTime'
        AND
        'secondTime'
```

you can coalesce null values to 0 as required, or often when doing something like this i want to group by date and then do a sum() on relevant values

looking a little more at the SQL i *think* it should work, though i guess i would write the inner query slightly differently:

```
Select 
    d.Date
    ,Projekt_ID
    ,Projektname
    ,Ist
FROM
    DatesTable as d
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
            SELECT 
                id AS Projekt_ID
                ,cu.name AS Projektname
                ,effort AS Ist 
                ,te.date
            FROM 
                (
                    SELECT 
                        p.cost_unit_id
                        ,SUM(te.effort) AS effort
                        ,p.id AS id
                        ,te.date
                    FROM 
                        time_entry te
                        inner join activity a
                            on te.task = a.uuid 
                        inner join  project 
                            on a.costunit = p.cost_unit_id 
                    GROUP BY 
                        p.cost_unit_id
                        ,p.id
                        ,te.date
                        ) as te 
                LEFT OUTER JOIN cost_unit cu 
                    ON cu.uuid = te.cost_unit_id
            WHERE id = " + ar[0]"
            ) i
        on d.Date = i.Date
    WHERE
        d.date BETWEEN
        'firstTime'
        AND
        'secondTime'
```

Comment: I got a table with time entries, in which every time entry has a date. Those time entries are summed to get an overall time entry for the whole time between my variables, for example:

Project ID - Name - Date - TimeSpent
22 - TimeEntry#1 - 2015-06-01 -  2,5
23 - TimeEntry#2 - 2015-06-01 - 1,0
22 - TimeEntry#3 - 2015-07-01 - 3,0
22 - TimeEntry#3 - 2015-07-15 - 1,9

If my query is to get those time entries between 1st July and 31st July I would geht Project ID 22 with 4,9 hours.

Comment: That is absolutely correct and is working. But I don't get anything from Project 23 as there were no Time Entries in that time, but I would need the project with the time entry 0,0 for that time between first and 31st july

Comment: I do not have an own table with the dates. The dates are a column on the time entry table, as mentioned in te.date BETWEEN x and y

Comment: You need to create the date table, its like a number table: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11506/why-are-numbers-tables-invaluable if you give some example data in tables (preferreably in SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/) with expected output it will save a lot of time.

Comment: I cannot change the table as it is a fix table I have to work with

Comment: it is a new table that you add to the database. which database engine are you using? normally your alternatives to adding a table like this are using a cursor or doing this outside of the DB. maybe there is some new methods in later db engines that give other options.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get 0 instead of null returning in SUM(te.effort) try to use isnull. For example:

> SELECT id AS Projekt_ID, cu.name AS Projektname, isnull(effort,0) AS Ist

But I notesed, that you get only Projekt_ID and Projektname. May be you also want to see activity in your query? For this you also need to left join activity table

```
SELECT id AS Projekt_ID, cu.name AS Projektname, a.activityname, isnull(effort,0) AS Ist 
FROM cost_unit cu 
LEFT OUTER JOIN activity a on 1=1
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT p.cost_unit_id, SUM(te.effort) AS effort, p.id AS id
    FROM time_entry te, project p, activity a
    WHERE te.task = a.uuid AND a.costunit = p.cost_unit_id AND te.date BETWEEN
            'firstTime'
            AND
            'secondTime'
    GROUP BY p.cost_unit_id, p.id) te 
ON cu.uuid = te.cost_unit_id
                    WHERE id = " + ar[0]
```

Comment: I don't need the activity, as that table is only a bridge between the other tables. I really only need the Project ID, the name and the time entires as a sum between the time i tell the query.

Comment: so if there is no activity between your dates, use isnull and you'll get 0

Comment: i did SELECT id AS Projekt_ID, cu.name AS Projektname, isnull(effort,0) AS Ist FROM cost_unit cu and get that error now

ERROR: function isnull(double precision, integer) does not exist
  Hinweis: No function matches the given name and argument types. You may need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: also, as it is a double, isnull(effort, 0.00) throws the same error

Comment: Hmmm.. Isnull common function for MSSQL.What kind DB you are using? MySQL, Oracle?

Comment: postgreSQL is what I am using

Comment: googled it, coalesced is it for postgresql, just trying it now

Comment: Use coalesce(effort, 0) instead isnull(effort,0)

Comment: with coalesce it is still not working, the projects are still not printed when there are no time entries in the time given

Comment: I think it is not working because not only the time entry as sum is empty in that case, as there is also no given project id or project name when they are not in that time given

Comment: Got it. Making new answer. Your ID field is not from cost_unit, but from subquery with LEFT join.